# Kali Software Center No Application Data Found

Tags: kali-linux

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

```
Linux kali 5.4.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1kali1 (2020-02-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is very important if used as native environment.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your repos file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://kali.download/kali/ kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

You may need to delete this bad PPA:

```
sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/PPA_name.list
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx man, I can't believe there was no answer in the whole internet. From the Kali community they didn't answer either. They still need to add a search field in the damn software-center :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally got it working in Kali

Answer (score 1):

You will need also update the gnome-software

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
sudo gnome-software
```

Also use main server and check all checkboxes in options

[image]

Comment: Thnx, but this is already installed from the beginning.

Comment: @DimDak it was also installed for me, but a reinstall actually fixed the issue ("sudo apt reinstall gnome-software")

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some one is still struggling to find solution for this
Following command worked for me.

The Idea is to clean the catalog cache of the gnome-softwares
For me it was at `~/.cache/gnome-software`
So just running following command worked for me

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/gnome-software
```

How did I find the folder?
I simply ran following command to find all caching related folders

```
ls -R / | grep cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in the terminal:

1. git clone https://github.com/preetam221/kali-linux-frontend-package-management
2. cd kali-linux-frontend-package-management/
3. sudo ./config-dev-v1.0.1

And complete the setup.
After completing the set up, launch the app store from your app menu.